# How do I fix error in visual studio code of submodules not opening/cloning correctly?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-submodules

I am trying to use an api for dolphin emulator and keep on getting the error "The "dolphin" repository has 18 submodules which won't be opened automatically. You can still open each one individually by opening a file within.". How do I make it so that they open automatically, and how do I actually find which submodules aren't opening and then open them(opening a file inside isn't working)? The submodules not opening is causing problems when I am trying to build the .sln file to make it work. I am using Git. There is an error message at the end of the cloning that I am not sure what it means or how I could fix it. Anyone know how to do so?

Here is the output for cloning the repo:

```
C:\Users\License_Name\Downloads\Dolphin modded>git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/Felk/dolphin.git
Cloning into 'dolphin'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 436701, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (7/7), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 436701 (delta 4), reused 4 (delta 4), pack-reused 436694
Receiving objects: 100% (436701/436701), 433.07 MiB | 5.72 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (344859/344859), done.
Updating files: 100% (6680/6680), done.
Submodule 'Externals/FFmpeg-bin' (https://github.com/dolphin-emu/ext-win-ffmpeg.git) registered for path 'Externals/FFmpeg-bin'
Submodule 'Externals/Qt' (https://github.com/dolphin-emu/ext-win-qt.git) registered for path 'Externals/Qt'
Submodule 'SDL' (https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL.git) registered for path 'Externals/SDL/SDL'
Submodule 'Externals/VulkanMemoryAllocator' (https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/VulkanMemoryAllocator.git) registered for path 'Externals/VulkanMemoryAllocator'
Submodule 'Externals/cubeb/cubeb' (https://github.com/mozilla/cubeb.git) registered for path 'Externals/cubeb/cubeb'
Submodule 'Externals/curl/curl' (https://github.com/curl/curl.git) registered for path 'Externals/curl/curl'
Submodule 'Externals/fmt/fmt' (https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt.git) registered for path 'Externals/fmt/fmt'
Submodule 'Externals/gtest' (https://github.com/google/googletest.git) registered for path 'Externals/gtest'
Submodule 'Externals/implot/implot' (https://github.com/epezent/implot.git) registered for path 'Externals/implot/implot'
Submodule 'Externals/libadrenotools' (https://github.com/bylaws/libadrenotools.git) registered for path 'Externals/libadrenotools'
Submodule 'Externals/libspng/libspng' (https://github.com/randy408/libspng.git) registered for path 'Externals/libspng/libspng'
Submodule 'libusb' (https://github.com/libusb/libusb.git) registered for path 'Externals/libusb/libusb'
Submodule 'Externals/lz4/lz4' (https://github.com/lz4/lz4) registered for path 'Externals/lz4/lz4'
Submodule 'Externals/mGBA/mgba' (https://github.com/mgba-emu/mgba.git) registered for path 'Externals/mGBA/mgba'
Submodule 'Externals/python' (https://github.com/Felk/ext-python.git) registered for path 'Externals/python'
Submodule 'Externals/rcheevos/rcheevos' (https://github.com/RetroAchievements/rcheevos.git) registered for path 'Externals/rcheevos/rcheevos'
Submodule 'Externals/spirv_cross/SPIRV-Cross' (https://github.com/KhronosGroup/SPIRV-Cross.git) registered for path 'Externals/spirv_cross/SPIRV-Cross'
Submodule 'Externals/zlib-ng/zlib-ng' (https://github.com/zlib-ng/zlib-ng.git) registered for path 'Externals/zlib-ng/zlib-ng'
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/FFmpeg-bin'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 152, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (152/152), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (123/123), done.
remote: Total 152 (delta 29), reused 152 (delta 29), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (152/152), 11.75 MiB | 7.21 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (29/29), done.
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/Qt'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 2215, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (2215/2215), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1413/1413), done.
remote: Total 2215 (delta 350), reused 2179 (delta 326), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (2215/2215), 89.60 MiB | 4.68 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (350/350), done.
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/SDL/SDL'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 23950, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (23950/23950), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (10674/10674), done.
remote: Total 23950 (delta 17342), reused 16805 (delta 11724), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (23950/23950), 24.42 MiB | 6.23 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (17342/17342), done.
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/VulkanMemoryAllocator'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 10405, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (2005/2005), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (353/353), done.
remote: Total 10405 (delta 1733), reused 1771 (delta 1612), pack-reused 8400
Receiving objects: 100% (10405/10405), 26.42 MiB | 6.38 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (8209/8209), done.
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/cubeb/cubeb'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 627, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (627/627), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (450/450), done.
remote: Total 627 (delta 413), reused 277 (delta 137), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (627/627), 515.56 KiB | 3.71 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (413/413), done.
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/curl/curl'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 209969, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (5425/5425), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (613/613), done.
remote: Total 209969 (delta 4931), reused 5147 (delta 4812), pack-reused 204544
Receiving objects: 100% (209969/209969), 64.58 MiB | 6.36 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (166357/166357), done.
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/fmt/fmt'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 35049, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (35049/35049), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (8543/8543), done.
remote: Total 35049 (delta 23840), reused 34816 (delta 23725), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (35049/35049), 14.41 MiB | 6.08 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (23840/23840), done.
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/gtest'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 27328, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (367/367), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (194/194), done.
remote: Total 27328 (delta 223), reused 211 (delta 153), pack-reused 26961
Receiving objects: 100% (27328/27328), 12.86 MiB | 5.52 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (20257/20257), done.
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/implot/implot'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 2574, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (710/710), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (76/76), done.
remote: Total 2574 (delta 657), reused 638 (delta 634), pack-reused 1864
Receiving objects: 100% (2574/2574), 1.61 MiB | 6.66 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1671/1671), done.
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/libadrenotools'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 223, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (36/36), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (27/27), done.
remote: Total 223 (delta 10), reused 17 (delta 5), pack-reused 187
Receiving objects: 100% (223/223), 138.08 KiB | 10.62 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (109/109), done.
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/libspng/libspng'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 1048, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1048/1048), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (683/683), done.
remote: Total 1048 (delta 566), reused 748 (delta 330), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (1048/1048), 404.12 KiB | 4.87 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (566/566), done.
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/libusb/libusb'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 4544, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (4544/4544), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1575/1575), done.
remote: Total 4544 (delta 3509), reused 3792 (delta 2900), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (4544/4544), 2.02 MiB | 7.91 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3509/3509), done.
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/lz4/lz4'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 15889, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1778/1778), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (691/691), done.
remote: Total 15889 (delta 1187), reused 1480 (delta 1067), pack-reused 14111
Receiving objects: 100% (15889/15889), 6.93 MiB | 4.25 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (10975/10975), done.
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/mGBA/mgba'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 12580, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (12580/12580), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (8204/8204), done.
remote: Total 12580 (delta 7920), reused 7970 (delta 4146), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (12580/12580), 27.92 MiB | 6.33 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (7920/7920), done.
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/python'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 833, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (474/474), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (308/308), done.
remote: Total 833 (delta 204), reused 344 (delta 166), pack-reused 359
Receiving objects: 100% (833/833), 48.85 MiB | 4.89 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (326/326), done.
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/rcheevos/rcheevos'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 4639, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (2299/2299), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (672/672), done.
remote: Total 4639 (delta 1954), reused 1830 (delta 1621), pack-reused 2340
Receiving objects: 100% (4639/4639), 2.01 MiB | 6.27 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3155/3155), done.
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/spirv_cross/SPIRV-Cross'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 10282, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (10282/10282), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (5064/5064), done.
remote: Total 10282 (delta 6940), reused 7687 (delta 5104), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (10282/10282), 3.32 MiB | 9.03 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (6940/6940), done.
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/zlib-ng/zlib-ng'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 5113, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (5113/5113), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2601/2601), done.
remote: Total 5113 (delta 3273), reused 4008 (delta 2420), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (5113/5113), 5.46 MiB | 8.46 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3273/3273), done.
Submodule path 'Externals/FFmpeg-bin': checked out '9bc087fbca36ce5a85eb4fd73f0c73813593e5a2'
Submodule path 'Externals/Qt': checked out '495517af2b922c10c24f543e0fd6ea3ddf774e50'
Submodule path 'Externals/SDL/SDL': checked out 'ac13ca9ab691e13e8eebe9684740ddcb0d716203'
Submodule path 'Externals/VulkanMemoryAllocator': checked out '498e20dfd1343d99b9115201034bb0219801cdec'
remote: Enumerating objects: 6764, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (6258/6258), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1766/1766), done.
Receiving objects: 100% (6090/6090), 2.43 MiB | 2.74 MiB/s, done.
remote: Total 6090 (delta 4420), reused 5785 (delta 4176), pack-reused 0
Resolving deltas: 100% (4420/4420), completed with 81 local objects.
From https://github.com/mozilla/cubeb
 * branch            27d2a102b0b75d9e49d43bc1ea516233fb87d778 -> FETCH_HEAD
Submodule path 'Externals/cubeb/cubeb': checked out '27d2a102b0b75d9e49d43bc1ea516233fb87d778'
Submodule 'cmake/sanitizers-cmake' (https://github.com/arsenm/sanitizers-cmake) registered for path 'Externals/cubeb/cubeb/cmake/sanitizers-cmake'
Submodule 'googletest' (https://github.com/google/googletest) registered for path 'Externals/cubeb/cubeb/googletest'
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/cubeb/cubeb/cmake/sanitizers-cmake'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 252, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (96/96), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
remote: Total 252 (delta 84), reused 79 (delta 77), pack-reused 156
Receiving objects: 100% (252/252), 55.82 KiB | 11.16 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (160/160), done.
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/cubeb/cubeb/googletest'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 27328, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (367/367), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (194/194), done.
remote: Total 27328 (delta 223), reused 211 (delta 153), pack-reused 26961
Receiving objects: 100% (27328/27328), 12.86 MiB | 3.80 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (20257/20257), done.
Submodule path 'Externals/cubeb/cubeb/cmake/sanitizers-cmake': checked out 'aab6948fa863bc1cbe5d0850bc46b9ef02ed4c1a'
Submodule path 'Externals/cubeb/cubeb/googletest': checked out '800f5422ac9d9e0ad59cd860a2ef3a679588acb4'
Submodule path 'Externals/curl/curl': checked out '7ab9d43720bc34d9aa351c7ca683c1668ebf8335'
Submodule path 'Externals/fmt/fmt': checked out 'f5e54359df4c26b6230fc61d38aa294581393084'
Submodule path 'Externals/gtest': checked out '58d77fa8070e8cec2dc1ed015d66b454c8d78850'
Submodule path 'Externals/implot/implot': checked out 'cc5e1daa5c7f2335a9460ae79c829011dc5cef2d'
Submodule path 'Externals/libadrenotools': checked out 'f4ce3c9618e7ecfcdd238b17dad9a0b888f5de90'
Submodule 'lib/linkernsbypass' (https://github.com/bylaws/liblinkernsbypass/) registered for path 'Externals/libadrenotools/lib/linkernsbypass'
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/libadrenotools/lib/linkernsbypass'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 26, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (21/21), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.
remote: Total 26 (delta 11), reused 14 (delta 7), pack-reused 5
Receiving objects: 100% (26/26), 10.28 KiB | 10.28 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (11/11), done.
Submodule path 'Externals/libadrenotools/lib/linkernsbypass': checked out '2f8df932534999196751dde3e0302f83ef1f4513'
remote: Enumerating objects: 154, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (105/105), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (31/31), done.
remote: Total 54 (delta 31), reused 40 (delta 23), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (54/54), 7.30 KiB | 43.00 KiB/s, done.
From https://github.com/randy408/libspng
 * branch            dc5b1032c08efac68ad30170f7ccbf0aa8dd55c9 -> FETCH_HEAD
Submodule path 'Externals/libspng/libspng': checked out 'dc5b1032c08efac68ad30170f7ccbf0aa8dd55c9'
remote: Enumerating objects: 86, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (72/72), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
remote: Total 16 (delta 10), reused 12 (delta 6), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (16/16), 2.99 KiB | 49.00 KiB/s, done.
From https://github.com/libusb/libusb
 * branch            ba698478afc3d3a72644eef9fc4cd24ce8383a4c -> FETCH_HEAD
Submodule path 'Externals/libusb/libusb': checked out 'ba698478afc3d3a72644eef9fc4cd24ce8383a4c'
Submodule path 'Externals/lz4/lz4': checked out '5fc0630a0ed55e9755b0fe3990cd021ae1c3edc1'
remote: Enumerating objects: 4382, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (3205/3205), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (695/695), done.
Receiving objects: 100% (2408/2408), 350.09 KiB | 7.00 MiB/s, done.
remote: Total 2408 (delta 1922), reused 2172 (delta 1698), pack-reused 0
Resolving deltas: 100% (1922/1922), completed with 258 local objects.
From https://github.com/mgba-emu/mgba
 * branch            8739b22fbc90fdf0b4f6612ef9c0520f0ba44a51 -> FETCH_HEAD
Submodule path 'Externals/mGBA/mgba': checked out '8739b22fbc90fdf0b4f6612ef9c0520f0ba44a51'
Submodule path 'Externals/python': checked out '56bae2976e9618b3b75533a6a50bd926dea6704c'
Submodule path 'Externals/rcheevos/rcheevos': checked out 'd9e990e6d13527532b7e2bb23164a1f3b7f33bb5'
Submodule path 'Externals/spirv_cross/SPIRV-Cross': checked out '50b4d5389b6a06f86fb63a2848e1a7da6d9755ca'
remote: Enumerating objects: 4202, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (3222/3222), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (816/816), done.
remote: Total 2569 (delta 1981), reused 2269 (delta 1691), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (2569/2569), 541.15 KiB | 8.20 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1981/1981), completed with 214 local objects.
From https://github.com/zlib-ng/zlib-ng
 * branch            ce01b1e41da298334f8214389cc9369540a7560f -> FETCH_HEAD
Submodule path 'Externals/zlib-ng/zlib-ng': checked out 'ce01b1e41da298334f8214389cc9369540a7560f'
 ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.n modded>
```

Comment: @phd I am not sure- I was pasting the error message that I got, and I thought it meant that it can't open them- as in read them in the app

Comment: @phd after re-cloning it and building it, I am still getting errors when I am building it - at the end I get the message: "========== Build: 35 succeeded, 8 failed, 0 up-to-date, 1 skipped ==========". do you know why this could be(it's the same error that I was getting before)?

Comment: this is what I am cloning: https://github.com/felk/dolphin - and when you say the entire output, do you mean the output from cloning it, or the output from recursing it?

Comment: there is no output when I run the command "git submodule update --init --recursive" - it takes a bit and then goes to another line waiting for me to input something - I am using "cd dolphin" beforehand to make sure i am in the file

Comment: @14sirs Thanks. "*…there is no output when I run the command…*" That probably normal. You did it immediately after cloning, so nothing to update. The command is intended to be run in a directory cloned without submodules. At the end of the cloning process I see a very strange error "' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file"; I don't understand it. Other than that all submodules were cloned, no errors.

Comment: @phd do you know why the error normally occurs? or do you have no idea why it occurs. I reopened the question so that I could potentially get help with it from others

Comment: You wouldn't get much help with the old question. My advice is to leave the question to a single error (cloning with submodules) and closed. Create a new question with more information, provide errors from compilation.

Comment: Ok, I shall do that, thank you for all your help!