Cloning with submodules using git error that a command is not recognized
I am trying to clone and use a dolphin API emulator for inserting code from github using git, the repo is this one: https://github.com/felk/dolphin. When I try to clone it, I get the error " ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.n modded> ". Anyone know why this is and how I could fix it so that it is cloned properly? This is causing issues when I try to build it since not all the files are copied. I am cloning it in terminal.
here is the output:
C:\Users\License_Name\Downloads\Dolphin modded>git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/Felk/dolphin.git
Cloning into 'dolphin'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 436701, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (7/7), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 436701 (delta 4), reused 4 (delta 4), pack-reused 436694
Receiving objects: 100% (436701/436701), 433.07 MiB | 5.72 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (344859/344859), done.
Updating files: 100% (6680/6680), done.
Submodule 'Externals/FFmpeg-bin' (https://github.com/dolphin-emu/ext-win-ffmpeg.git) registered for path 'Externals/FFmpeg-bin'
Submodule 'Externals/Qt' (https://github.com/dolphin-emu/ext-win-qt.git) registered for path 'Externals/Qt'
Submodule 'SDL' (https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL.git) registered for path 'Externals/SDL/SDL'
Submodule 'Externals/VulkanMemoryAllocator' (https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/VulkanMemoryAllocator.git) registered for path 'Externals/VulkanMemoryAllocator'
Submodule 'Externals/cubeb/cubeb' (https://github.com/mozilla/cubeb.git) registered for path 'Externals/cubeb/cubeb'
Submodule 'Externals/curl/curl' (https://github.com/curl/curl.git) registered for path 'Externals/curl/curl'
Submodule 'Externals/fmt/fmt' (https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt.git) registered for path 'Externals/fmt/fmt'
Submodule 'Externals/gtest' (https://github.com/google/googletest.git) registered for path 'Externals/gtest'
Submodule 'Externals/implot/implot' (https://github.com/epezent/implot.git) registered for path 'Externals/implot/implot'
Submodule 'Externals/libadrenotools' (https://github.com/bylaws/libadrenotools.git) registered for path 'Externals/libadrenotools'
Submodule 'Externals/libspng/libspng' (https://github.com/randy408/libspng.git) registered for path 'Externals/libspng/libspng'
Submodule 'libusb' (https://github.com/libusb/libusb.git) registered for path 'Externals/libusb/libusb'
Submodule 'Externals/lz4/lz4' (https://github.com/lz4/lz4) registered for path 'Externals/lz4/lz4'
Submodule 'Externals/mGBA/mgba' (https://github.com/mgba-emu/mgba.git) registered for path 'Externals/mGBA/mgba'
Submodule 'Externals/python' (https://github.com/Felk/ext-python.git) registered for path 'Externals/python'
Submodule 'Externals/rcheevos/rcheevos' (https://github.com/RetroAchievements/rcheevos.git) registered for path 'Externals/rcheevos/rcheevos'
Submodule 'Externals/spirv_cross/SPIRV-Cross' (https://github.com/KhronosGroup/SPIRV-Cross.git) registered for path 'Externals/spirv_cross/SPIRV-Cross'
Submodule 'Externals/zlib-ng/zlib-ng' (https://github.com/zlib-ng/zlib-ng.git) registered for path 'Externals/zlib-ng/zlib-ng'
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/FFmpeg-bin'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 152, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (152/152), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (123/123), done.
remote: Total 152 (delta 29), reused 152 (delta 29), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (152/152), 11.75 MiB | 7.21 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (29/29), done.
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/Qt'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 2215, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (2215/2215), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1413/1413), done.
remote: Total 2215 (delta 350), reused 2179 (delta 326), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (2215/2215), 89.60 MiB | 4.68 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (350/350), done.
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/SDL/SDL'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 23950, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (23950/23950), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (10674/10674), done.
remote: Total 23950 (delta 17342), reused 16805 (delta 11724), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (23950/23950), 24.42 MiB | 6.23 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (17342/17342), done.
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/VulkanMemoryAllocator'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 10405, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (2005/2005), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (353/353), done.
remote: Total 10405 (delta 1733), reused 1771 (delta 1612), pack-reused 8400
Receiving objects: 100% (10405/10405), 26.42 MiB | 6.38 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (8209/8209), done.
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/cubeb/cubeb'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 627, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (627/627), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (450/450), done.
remote: Total 627 (delta 413), reused 277 (delta 137), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (627/627), 515.56 KiB | 3.71 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (413/413), done.
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/curl/curl'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 209969, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (5425/5425), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (613/613), done.
remote: Total 209969 (delta 4931), reused 5147 (delta 4812), pack-reused 204544
Receiving objects: 100% (209969/209969), 64.58 MiB | 6.36 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (166357/166357), done.
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/fmt/fmt'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 35049, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (35049/35049), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (8543/8543), done.
remote: Total 35049 (delta 23840), reused 34816 (delta 23725), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (35049/35049), 14.41 MiB | 6.08 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (23840/23840), done.
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/gtest'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 27328, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (367/367), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (194/194), done.
remote: Total 27328 (delta 223), reused 211 (delta 153), pack-reused 26961
Receiving objects: 100% (27328/27328), 12.86 MiB | 5.52 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (20257/20257), done.
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/implot/implot'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 2574, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (710/710), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (76/76), done.
remote: Total 2574 (delta 657), reused 638 (delta 634), pack-reused 1864
Receiving objects: 100% (2574/2574), 1.61 MiB | 6.66 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1671/1671), done.
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/libadrenotools'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 223, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (36/36), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (27/27), done.
remote: Total 223 (delta 10), reused 17 (delta 5), pack-reused 187
Receiving objects: 100% (223/223), 138.08 KiB | 10.62 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (109/109), done.
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/libspng/libspng'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 1048, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1048/1048), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (683/683), done.
remote: Total 1048 (delta 566), reused 748 (delta 330), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (1048/1048), 404.12 KiB | 4.87 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (566/566), done.
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/libusb/libusb'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 4544, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (4544/4544), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1575/1575), done.
remote: Total 4544 (delta 3509), reused 3792 (delta 2900), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (4544/4544), 2.02 MiB | 7.91 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3509/3509), done.
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/lz4/lz4'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 15889, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1778/1778), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (691/691), done.
remote: Total 15889 (delta 1187), reused 1480 (delta 1067), pack-reused 14111
Receiving objects: 100% (15889/15889), 6.93 MiB | 4.25 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (10975/10975), done.
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/mGBA/mgba'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 12580, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (12580/12580), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (8204/8204), done.
remote: Total 12580 (delta 7920), reused 7970 (delta 4146), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (12580/12580), 27.92 MiB | 6.33 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (7920/7920), done.
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/python'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 833, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (474/474), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (308/308), done.
remote: Total 833 (delta 204), reused 344 (delta 166), pack-reused 359
Receiving objects: 100% (833/833), 48.85 MiB | 4.89 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (326/326), done.
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/rcheevos/rcheevos'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 4639, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (2299/2299), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (672/672), done.
remote: Total 4639 (delta 1954), reused 1830 (delta 1621), pack-reused 2340
Receiving objects: 100% (4639/4639), 2.01 MiB | 6.27 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3155/3155), done.
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/spirv_cross/SPIRV-Cross'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 10282, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (10282/10282), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (5064/5064), done.
remote: Total 10282 (delta 6940), reused 7687 (delta 5104), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (10282/10282), 3.32 MiB | 9.03 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (6940/6940), done.
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/zlib-ng/zlib-ng'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 5113, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (5113/5113), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2601/2601), done.
remote: Total 5113 (delta 3273), reused 4008 (delta 2420), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (5113/5113), 5.46 MiB | 8.46 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3273/3273), done.
Submodule path 'Externals/FFmpeg-bin': checked out '9bc087fbca36ce5a85eb4fd73f0c73813593e5a2'
Submodule path 'Externals/Qt': checked out '495517af2b922c10c24f543e0fd6ea3ddf774e50'
Submodule path 'Externals/SDL/SDL': checked out 'ac13ca9ab691e13e8eebe9684740ddcb0d716203'
Submodule path 'Externals/VulkanMemoryAllocator': checked out '498e20dfd1343d99b9115201034bb0219801cdec'
remote: Enumerating objects: 6764, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (6258/6258), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1766/1766), done.
Receiving objects: 100% (6090/6090), 2.43 MiB | 2.74 MiB/s, done.
remote: Total 6090 (delta 4420), reused 5785 (delta 4176), pack-reused 0
Resolving deltas: 100% (4420/4420), completed with 81 local objects.
From https://github.com/mozilla/cubeb
 * branch            27d2a102b0b75d9e49d43bc1ea516233fb87d778 -> FETCH_HEAD
Submodule path 'Externals/cubeb/cubeb': checked out '27d2a102b0b75d9e49d43bc1ea516233fb87d778'
Submodule 'cmake/sanitizers-cmake' (https://github.com/arsenm/sanitizers-cmake) registered for path 'Externals/cubeb/cubeb/cmake/sanitizers-cmake'
Submodule 'googletest' (https://github.com/google/googletest) registered for path 'Externals/cubeb/cubeb/googletest'
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/cubeb/cubeb/cmake/sanitizers-cmake'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 252, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (96/96), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
remote: Total 252 (delta 84), reused 79 (delta 77), pack-reused 156
Receiving objects: 100% (252/252), 55.82 KiB | 11.16 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (160/160), done.
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/cubeb/cubeb/googletest'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 27328, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (367/367), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (194/194), done.
remote: Total 27328 (delta 223), reused 211 (delta 153), pack-reused 26961
Receiving objects: 100% (27328/27328), 12.86 MiB | 3.80 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (20257/20257), done.
Submodule path 'Externals/cubeb/cubeb/cmake/sanitizers-cmake': checked out 'aab6948fa863bc1cbe5d0850bc46b9ef02ed4c1a'
Submodule path 'Externals/cubeb/cubeb/googletest': checked out '800f5422ac9d9e0ad59cd860a2ef3a679588acb4'
Submodule path 'Externals/curl/curl': checked out '7ab9d43720bc34d9aa351c7ca683c1668ebf8335'
Submodule path 'Externals/fmt/fmt': checked out 'f5e54359df4c26b6230fc61d38aa294581393084'
Submodule path 'Externals/gtest': checked out '58d77fa8070e8cec2dc1ed015d66b454c8d78850'
Submodule path 'Externals/implot/implot': checked out 'cc5e1daa5c7f2335a9460ae79c829011dc5cef2d'
Submodule path 'Externals/libadrenotools': checked out 'f4ce3c9618e7ecfcdd238b17dad9a0b888f5de90'
Submodule 'lib/linkernsbypass' (https://github.com/bylaws/liblinkernsbypass/) registered for path 'Externals/libadrenotools/lib/linkernsbypass'
Cloning into 'C:/Users/License_Name/Downloads/Dolphin modded/dolphin/Externals/libadrenotools/lib/linkernsbypass'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 26, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (21/21), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.
remote: Total 26 (delta 11), reused 14 (delta 7), pack-reused 5
Receiving objects: 100% (26/26), 10.28 KiB | 10.28 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (11/11), done.
Submodule path 'Externals/libadrenotools/lib/linkernsbypass': checked out '2f8df932534999196751dde3e0302f83ef1f4513'
remote: Enumerating objects: 154, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (105/105), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (31/31), done.
remote: Total 54 (delta 31), reused 40 (delta 23), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (54/54), 7.30 KiB | 43.00 KiB/s, done.
From https://github.com/randy408/libspng
 * branch            dc5b1032c08efac68ad30170f7ccbf0aa8dd55c9 -> FETCH_HEAD
Submodule path 'Externals/libspng/libspng': checked out 'dc5b1032c08efac68ad30170f7ccbf0aa8dd55c9'
remote: Enumerating objects: 86, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (72/72), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
remote: Total 16 (delta 10), reused 12 (delta 6), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (16/16), 2.99 KiB | 49.00 KiB/s, done.
From https://github.com/libusb/libusb
 * branch            ba698478afc3d3a72644eef9fc4cd24ce8383a4c -> FETCH_HEAD
Submodule path 'Externals/libusb/libusb': checked out 'ba698478afc3d3a72644eef9fc4cd24ce8383a4c'
Submodule path 'Externals/lz4/lz4': checked out '5fc0630a0ed55e9755b0fe3990cd021ae1c3edc1'
remote: Enumerating objects: 4382, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (3205/3205), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (695/695), done.
Receiving objects: 100% (2408/2408), 350.09 KiB | 7.00 MiB/s, done.
remote: Total 2408 (delta 1922), reused 2172 (delta 1698), pack-reused 0
Resolving deltas: 100% (1922/1922), completed with 258 local objects.
From https://github.com/mgba-emu/mgba
 * branch            8739b22fbc90fdf0b4f6612ef9c0520f0ba44a51 -> FETCH_HEAD
Submodule path 'Externals/mGBA/mgba': checked out '8739b22fbc90fdf0b4f6612ef9c0520f0ba44a51'
Submodule path 'Externals/python': checked out '56bae2976e9618b3b75533a6a50bd926dea6704c'
Submodule path 'Externals/rcheevos/rcheevos': checked out 'd9e990e6d13527532b7e2bb23164a1f3b7f33bb5'
Submodule path 'Externals/spirv_cross/SPIRV-Cross': checked out '50b4d5389b6a06f86fb63a2848e1a7da6d9755ca'
remote: Enumerating objects: 4202, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (3222/3222), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (816/816), done.
remote: Total 2569 (delta 1981), reused 2269 (delta 1691), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (2569/2569), 541.15 KiB | 8.20 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1981/1981), completed with 214 local objects.
From https://github.com/zlib-ng/zlib-ng
 * branch            ce01b1e41da298334f8214389cc9369540a7560f -> FETCH_HEAD
Submodule path 'Externals/zlib-ng/zlib-ng': checked out 'ce01b1e41da298334f8214389cc9369540a7560f'
 ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.n modded>


I'd like to point that this is a continuation from https://stackoverflow.com/q/78192495/7976758

Your repo can be downloaded just fine.
If you try to launch git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/Felk/dolphin.git again in another folder, you'll see that your repo will be downloaded and its submodules initialized correctly.
When you've launched your command, you must have accidentally entered an apostrophe during the cloning. In fact, if you pay attention to the command's log, you can see that there are actually no errors. It just says at the very end:
' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

which is referred to the apostrophe you've entered by mistake, not to the git clone. In fact, if you open a new command prompt window and enter ' right away, you would get the same message again.

I have just rerun the command without pressing keyboard and that has worked, I am not sure how I got the error multiple times before, but thank you very much for the help

@14sirs It says error MSB8013: This project doesn't contain the Configuration and Platform combination of Debug|Win32. It seems like that the machine where you're building your project is missing some necessary configurations. This is another problem that should be opened in a separate question. The cloning has nothing to do with it. My post answers your question regarding the error message given during the clone.

I still am getting the error of "The "dolphin" repository has 18 submodules which won't be opened automatically. You can still open each one individually by opening a file within." in visual studio code when I am opening it. Do you have any idea why this is?

@14siris Again the question is about the error message "` is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." Keep re-opening the same question for issues that arise after the first problem is solved is not the way to go. The post I've provided answers your original question. If now you're having another problem with the repo's submodules instead of it's clone, I'll be happy to help you with it, but you need to open a new question.

Ok, I thought that this was part of the same question, sorry

@14sirs No worries or apologies needed! :) Just open a new question and provide it with the error message you're getting. As it is now, my post answers this question. I'll look into your next one and hope to be able to help you with that one too.
